# Round number problem involving CLT.

Tags: probability, statistics

Every time Jim uses his credit card, he rounds the amount he was charged to the nearest dollar
in his records. Assume the number of cents involved in each purchase is a uniformly distributed
whole number between 0 and 99. He has used the credit card a total of 150 times.

(a) If the total amount in Jim's records differs from the actual total by \$10, what is the mean error (difference between amount charged and amount recorded) per purchase?

(b) Find the probability that the total amount in Jim's records differs from the actual total by more than \$10. (Hint: The Central Limit Theorem implies the distribution of the mean
error per purchase in a random sample of 150 purchases is normal)

---

a) I think the answer should be $\frac{10}{150} \approx \$0.07$ per purchase.

b) I do not know how to solve this problem. Here is what I have done so far:

Let $X$ be the random variable for the error in total.

Since the number in cents is selected in the discrete interval $[0,99]$ randomly, the probability for rounding any price amount is $p = 0.5$ because for the first 50 digits [0 , 49], we don't round, but we round for [50 , 99]. Then...

$\bar X = 0.005{}\cdot{}150 = \$0.75$

$ \mu  = \$10 $? I don't really know what to put here. I guess it is given by the problem.

$\sigma^2 = E[(X-\mu)^2] = \frac {1}{100} 2(0^2 +0.1^2 +...+0.50^2)= 0.4583 $

$  \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{150}} = 0.05528$

$P( Z > \frac{\bar X-\mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}) = 1- P( Z < \frac{0.75-10}{0.05528}) = 1 - P( Z < -167.33)$ ... whose z value is too big to be on the z-table.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The hint seems off since CLT applies when dividing by srt(n), not n. But here you have iid $\{Y_i\}$, you can either model them as continuous uniform $[-50,50]$, or discrete uniform $\{-49,-48,...49,50\}$. Then apply CLT as usual.  It means you must pick a distribution to assume, then get E[Y] and  Var[Y].

Comment: Please, don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired. Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources.

Comment: Since Jim *rounds* to the nearest integer, the error is uniformly distributed between $-1/2$ and $1/2$ (dollars).  The mean error is zero.  You can treat the error as discrete or continuous, it shouldn't make much difference either way.

Comment: I think the mean is 0.005, because $ \frac {(0.5 + 0.49 + ... + 0 + (-0.01) + ... + (-0.49))}{100} = \frac {0.5}{100} = 0.005$ because once the number reaches 50 cents, it gets rounded so -0.5 is not considered. @awkward

Comment: That's the kind of effect I was referring to when I said you can model the error as continuous or discrete.  I don't think it will make much difference in the end, but do it either way you like.

Comment: Could you give me a solution for this problem using discrete please? @awkward

Comment: Looking at your solution again, I think the main problem is that what you have called $\overline{X}$ is not the average of the errors, it is the sum.  So you need to use the standard deviation of the sum of the errors, not the average, in your $Z$ calculation.

Comment: Note, however, that your solution depends on your assumption that Jim always rounds up on $50$ cents.  Other methods are possible, such as "round half to even", which results in an average error of zero. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding